# Remove class using index

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might be easy but I am having trouble in getting it to work. I am using .each() to iterate through a list. I was wondering if it is possible to remove a class using the index.

eg. If there were 10 items in the list and I want to remove the class from the 5th element when I click the 8th element for example.

```
$(function () {
var items = $('#v-nav>ul>li').each(function (index) {
    $(this).click(function () {
        if (index = 8)
{
$(#5).removeClass('class');
}
    });
});
```

Anyone with any ideas? Thank you

Comment: You don't need top iterate all the `li` elements, instead you can directly add an event handler on the targeted `li`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
$(#5).removeClass('class');
```

To

```
$('#v-nav>ul>li:eq(4)').removeClass('class');
```

Its better to assign the element returned by your selector to do the same processing again to get desired element.

```
$(function () {
    var items = $('#v-nav>ul>li')

       $('#v-nav>ul>li').click(function () {
          if ($(this).index() = 8)
          {
             $(items).eq(4).removeClass('class');
          }
       });
});
```

Comment: Where am I iterating? and in OP "I want to remove the class from the 5th element when I click the 8th element for example"

Comment: Oops! No, you are not iterating, it's for the `OP`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to iterate with `each()`, as each element already has an index, and using `eq()` will let you select elements based on the index they have in the DOM. This solution is dependant on the elements being siblings() etc.

```
$(function () {
    var elems = $('#v-nav>ul>li');

    elems.on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).index()==8) elems.eq(4).removeClass('class');
    });
});
```

You could also just bind the click to that one element:

```
$(function () {
    $('#v-nav>ul>li:eq(7)').on('click', function() {
         $(this).siblings().filter(':eq(4)').removeClass('class');
    });
});
```

Otherwise I would just do:

```
$(function () {
    var elems = $('#v-nav>ul>li');
    $.each(elems, function(idx, elm) {
        if (idx==8) elems.eq(4).removeClass('class');
    });
});
```

As a sidenote ID's consisting of just a number (or starting with a number) is invalid.

Comment: Looks like eq(5)  is supposed to be eq(4)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to iterate over all the `li` elements, instead you can do it like this way

```
$(function(){
  $('#v-nav>ul>li').eq(7).on('click', function(){ // eq(7) is 8th li
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').eq(4).removeClass('cls'); //eq(4) is 5th li
  });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gWWu6/).